# How to add to Google bookmarks lists through the browser using Google toolbar, an extension or a bookmarklet?

Tags: google-chrome, google-bookmarks, google-toolbar

Google added a good feature for their bookmarks called lists, which will let me organize my bookmarks better.

Is there a way I can bookmark an URL directly to one of my Google Bookmarks lists?

Hope there is a bookmarklet, Chrome Extension or through Google Toolbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to the 'My Lists' section of Google Bookmarks (link is in the top left) and select a list you will see the following in the bottom right of the screen

```
Install the lists bookmarklet
Add Add to list to your bookmarks bar to add web pages from anywhere on the web.
```

Click and drag the blue 'Add to list' button to your bookmarks bar.

Comment: But like that i will have different bookmarklets for different list, right?